# console.log("x:", x) or console.log("x:" + x)?

Tags: javascript, console

Why is `console.log("x:", x)` better than `console.log("x:" + x)`? I have a category object that contains `categoryId` and `name`. When I write `console.log("x:", x)`, the console gives me
`Data: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

However, if I use `console.log("x:" + x)`, the console gives me
`Data: [object, object][object, object][object, object][object, object][object, object]`

I wonder what is the reason and why there is a difference?

Comment: is this about Js? well, `("x:",x)` writes it as it is and `("x:"+x)` will concatenate the value to string right? that's why preferred is the first one.

Comment: Why would you be using `+x` to begin with?

Comment: Yes, about Js. No particular reason. I think in java, when we print something in the console, we use +, that's why I assume here we can use + as well.

Comment: the first (with coma) add a space between ... so, what ever ?

Comment: the second (with `+`) try to convert the value to a string (because previous element is a string)... so,  what ever ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why using console.log("Data:"+x) does not output the desired result when console.log("Data:",x) does (x is the variable name of your object) is because of the way that JavaScript works. In the first example, Javascript will first evaluate the string passed as a parameter (the "Data:"+x).

Since JavaScript can only convert an object to a string when it is passed as an argument to a JSON.stringify() function, the object will not be preserved within the evaluation of the string, and it will instead be replaced with "[object Object]".

Javascript will interpret console.log("Data:",x) differently. The first parameter, "Data:", is passed and logged into the console first. In the same line, the data object is logged as an object datatype, as the object is not next to a string and therefore will not be evaluated as a string before being logged into the console.